# could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB: What does it mean, how to solve it?

Tags: android-emulator

I am new to android, when I launch my AVD then I get this message "could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB" in console of eclipse IDE.

Although application runs fine, but I wanted to ask what does this message means and should I ignore it or resolve it? If I should resolve it then how to do it?

The messages from console of eclipse IDE are given below:

```
[2012-07-24 13:02:05 - test] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'ICS'

[2012-07-24 13:02:05 - test] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'ICS'

[2012-07-24 13:02:22 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB

[2012-07-24 13:02:22 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005

[2012-07-24 13:02:22 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.

[2012-07-24 13:02:22 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

same as above line, then

```
[2012-07-24 13:02:22 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB

[2012-07-24 13:02:24 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio output failed

[2012-07-24 13:02:24 - Emulator] 

[2012-07-24 13:02:28 - test] New emulator found: emulator-5554
```